# Not able to install any module in drupal 8

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to install a module eu_cookie_compliance but not able to install this because of following error message.

Not only eu_cookie_compliance module I am not able to install any module which has implemented hook_schema in it because of below error.

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4': CREATE TABLE {eu_cookie_compliance_basic_consent} ( `cid` INT NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique consent storage ID.', `uid` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'users.uid for user.', `timestamp` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Time of consent.', `ip_address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The IP address.', `consent_type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The type of consent, such as "banner" for the banner and form_id for forms.', `revision_id` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Revision of the privacy policy at the time of consent.', PRIMARY KEY (`cid`), INDEX `uid` (`uid`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8_general_ci COMMENT 'Basic consent storage for EU Cookie Compliance / GDPR.'; Array ( ) in drupal_install_schema() (line 124 of /var/www/gcp/docroot/core/includes/schema.inc)

Not able to understand how to fix this. I tried more than 4 hours on google searching but did not get any solution.

Drupal Version: 8.8.8,
PHP Version: 7.4.7,
Mysql Version: 5.7.29,
Drupal VM

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is in `utf8_general_ci` and this SQL query expect `utf8mb4_general_ci` instead.

Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5 for more informations on how to convert an utf8 database to utf8mb4.